# Non-measurable set A such that $A \cap \mathbb{Q}^c$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does there exist a non-(Lebesgue)measurable set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $B = \{x \in A : x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} \}$ is measurable?

My thoughts: the only non-measurable sets I've seen so far are the Vitali sets, so thinking along this line - are the irrational points in a Vitali set $V$ measurable? It would be enough to show that their complement is measurable - that is, is the set $\{x \in V : x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ measurable? Since the set $V$ is obtained by taking the quotient group $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, the rational points are all in a single equivalence class represented by, say, $0$, which certainly is measurable as it is a singleton.

Is my thinking correct? If not, does there exist another example?

Comment: $V \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is measurable since it is countable.

Comment: Note that $A \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is Lebesgue measurable (as it is a subset of a null-set, or, if you prefer, because it is countable, therefore Borel measurable).  If $A \cap \mathbb{Q}^c$ is also measurable, then $A$ is the union of two measurable sets, therefore measurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Let $\mathbb{I}$ be the set of irrational numbers.

Let $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ non measurable.

If $V \cap \mathbb{I}$ is measurable with respect to the Lebesgue measure then $V \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is measurable as a set of  Lebesgue measure zero .

Thus $V=(V \cap \mathbb{I}) \cup (V \cap \mathbb{Q})$ would be measurable as a union of measurable sets.

This is a contradiction.

> Also note that the Lebesgue measure is complete so a subset of a set of Lebesgue measure zero is measurable.

Comment: @user726608 what sets are Q and B?

Comment: $Q$ denote the rationals,and  $A\subset R$ . can we find a non-Labesgue measurable set $A$ in $R$ such that this set contains $Q$.

Comment: I couldn't find an obvious example of this.

Comment: @user726608 take $V$ an non measurable set of the real line and then take $B=V \cup Q$... if $B$ was measurable then $V \cap Q^c=B \cap Q^c$ woulf be measurable thus $V=(V \cap Q^c )\cup (V \cap Q)$ would be measurable..Note that $V \cap Q$ is measurable as a set of measure zero

Comment: Marios Gretsas thanks, sorry I got lost, mu question was id there exist a non-Labesgue $B$ set in $R$ such that $Q\subset B$.  You showed that by contradiction right? $B\cap Q^c$ is measurable since B is and Q^c is (as the complement of a set of measure 0 )?

Comment: @user726608 i took the set B  and i proved by contradiction tha it is not measurable..so B satisfies your requirements.

Comment: So this claim is false right

Comment: @user726608   your question has an affirmative answer..there exists a non measurable set that contains all the rationals..i found one and i proved that indeed is not measurable.